# How to construct BaseClass kind of structure for test suite driven by TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I have built a sizable TestNg driven API tests using core Java & maven.

I have Java classes for various API end point.
Under this class, using TestNG's @BeforeTest annotation, I initialise
Restassured Endpoints & select a environment (out of Mock/prod/pre/qa etc)

```
public class MY_PUBLIC_API_PRISM_GET_ACCOUNTS {
    Response response;
    EndPoints endpoints;
    String jwtToken = "";


    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest(ITestContext itestContext) {
        endpoints = new EndPoints();
        jwtToken= (String) itestContext.getAttribute("JWTToken");
        **endpoints.chooseEndPoint("PRISM_MOCK_PORT");** // <--- Environment //selection
    }
..
..
}
```

Unfortunately beforeTest boilercode is repeated in every classfile, as I can not have a BaseTestClass, as tests are controlled by TestNG
I would like to avoid repeating & have this at one place, so as I can efficiently handle the end-point selection.
How to achieve this? given the fact that, its using TestNG framework, thus if I try to construct something like BaseTest Class using Java, then I am getting Nullpointerexception.
Thanks

Comment: Why exactly can't you have a(n abstract) base class that only defines the `@BeforeTest`-annotated method and then derive all test classes from that class? What exactly is then `null`?

Comment: Do you have code example for it? how to extract AbstractClass

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one at `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).